# How to convert a string to a block of code in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm developing  a simulator app in Xcode for iphone.
    I have a textfield and I'm writing some C code in that field. Is there any method to compile and run that block of code when I click a button. 
 I've read about NSTask. But I think NSTask is for calling an app from another app.
 My last option is to split up the string from the textfield and analyse each of them and make the output. But it will be very much complicated and time consuming. Is there any better way to do this.

Comment: can you write your code here...? for more understanding your issue

Comment: for that please refer apple official documentation for the Block http://goo.gl/VwtLH

Comment: @NitinGohel : My textfield string will be like this -- "int var1=0;if(var1<=0){var1=var1+2;}". From the above string what i want to do is, create a variable and execute the if statement.

Comment: Where are you going to get gcc or llvm on the phone?  Further, if you ever wanted to deploy this app on the App Store, you'd likely run afoul of [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) 2.8  What you're doing sounds interesting, but probably not feasible on iOS unless, as you suggest, you want to write your own compiler.

Comment: @NSBum : Is it possible by using some open source C intepreter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can somehow re-use the UIWebView javascript intepreter and re-interpret/convert objective-C code + syntax  into evaluatable javascript code. Is this making any sense?